# Can´t reach function when onclick is located in Site.Master

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Coding a page in asp.net webforms, I put a button and textbox in site.master file.
I want to do a specific action (defined in a method) when I click in button, so I put this method in site.master.cs. This method, besides other things, take the value of textbox.

I can´t reach the method when I am clicking in it.

Am I coding it in a proper way?
Are there another way to do it?

This is the relevant code.

**site.master**

```
<input id="mailListaD" type="text" value="Introduce tu Email&hellip;" runat="server"
 onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='Introduce tu Email&hellip;')? '' : this.value ;" />

<asp:Button id="news_go" Text="GO" OnClick="listaDistribucion_Click" runat="server"/>
```

**site.master.cs**

```
protected void listaDistribucion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO listaDistribucion VALUES(''," + mailListaD.Value +")";
    ExecuteQuery(query);
    Close();
}
```

The error when I compile the proyect is:

```
error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'sender' of 'SiteMaster.listaDistribucion_Click(object, EventArgs)'
```

Comment: Tip: You can use the html5 `placeholder` attribute and get rid of the initial value and onfocus

Comment: @bradbury9 Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try generating the event from the IntelliSense, delete the event that is attached to the button and then write OnClick=.. when intellisense appears click *Create New Event* and in the code behind you get an event that has the name of the id of the button and onclick appended to it.
Also check if you have the correct code behind page in your masterpage in the first line above CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.cs", check if the name of your code behind is correct.

Comment: Funny... It works without change the code. Cheers my friend.